# When is a directed graph an endofunction

Tags: graph-theory

A directed graph has a set of nodes and a set of directed edges.  We can take the set of nodes as the Domain of a function, and the edges are the function assignments of some function.  Naturally, if any node has two edges emitting from it, the graph is not a function.  If there is a node without an edge emitting from it, it is not a function (though perhaps is a partial function).  What are the special properties of graphs that are exactly equal to endofunctions on the set of nodes?  What is the name for these graphs?

Comment: what is the codomain?

Comment: regular one-degree out graphs

Comment: Isn't the codomain just the set of nodes?  It guess I am asking about endofunctions on the set of nodes.